# Icon image for rich:dataTable similar to rich:treeNode

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

Is it possible to have items in a rich:dataTable display with a different icon depending on their #{bean.type} similar to how you can alter the icon in a rich:tree and rich:treeNode?

Comment: can you please show some code?

Answer (score 1):

you can add a `<f:facet name="header">` in your rich column that can display any HTML, or in your rich column you can have any html which could be custom images.

you can add a `rendered` attribute to `<h:graphicImage>` based on the value of `#{bean.type}` or `#{bean.type}` could be a link to the image for  to get.
for example

```
<h:graphicImage value="/images/icons/tables/down_icon.gif" rendered="#{carsSortingBean.sortsOrders['mileage']=='descending'}" />
<h:graphicImage value="/images/icons/tables/up_icon.gif.gif"
                        rendered="#{carsSortingBean.sortsOrders['mileage']=='ascending'}" />
```

So yes. There are lots of way's to customize the output of a dataTable